# cannot in parsing nested xml structure

Tags: android, xml-parsing

this is my xml structure :

```
<menu>
<item_category>
<category_name>ICECREAM</category_name>
<item>
<item_name>SOFTY</item_name>
<item_price>7.00</item_price>
</item>
<item>
<item_name>STICK</item_name>
<item_price>15.00</item_price>
</item>
<item>
<item_name>CONE</item_name>
<item_price>25.00</item_price>
</item>
</item_category>
<item_category>
<category_name>PIZZA</category_name>
<item>
<item_name>PIZZA-HOT</item_name>
<item_price>35.00</item_price>
</item>
<item>
<item_name>PIZZA-CRISPY</item_name>
<item_price>29.00</item_price>
</item>
</item_category>
</menu>
```

this is my code where i am parsing into list view

```
public class AndroidXMLParsingActivity extends ListActivity {

    // All static variables
    //static final String URL = "http://api.androidhive.info/pizza/?format=xml";
    static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.112/dine/index.php/dineout/mob_view";
    //static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.112/dineout/index.php/dineout/view";

    // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_MENU= "menu"; // parent node
    //static final String KEY_ID = "foodjoint_id";
    static final String KEY_CATEGORY= "category_name";

    static final String KEY_ITEM= "item";
    static final String KEY_ITEM_NAME= "item_name";
    static final String KEY_PRICE= "item_price";


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

        XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
        String xml = parser.getXmlFromUrl(URL); // getting XML
        Document doc = parser.getDomElement(xml); // getting DOM element

        NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);


        // looping through all item nodes <item>
        for (int i = 0; i < nl.getLength(); i++) 
        {
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);

          map.put(KEY_CATEGORY, parser.getValue(e,KEY_CATEGORY));
         map.put(KEY_ITEM_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM_NAME));
           map.put(KEY_PRICE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRICE));



            menuItems.add(map);
            }


        // Adding menuItems to ListView
        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, menuItems,
                R.layout.list_item,
new String[] {KEY_CATEGORY,KEY_ITEM_NAME,KEY_PRICE}, new int[] {R.id.category,R.id.name,R.id.costlab });

        setListAdapter(adapter);

        // selecting single ListView item
        ListView lv = getListView();

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // getting values from selected ListItem
                String category = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.category)).getText().toString();
                String name = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name)).getText().toString();
                //String description = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.desciption)).getText().toString();
                String cost = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cost)).getText().toString();
                // Starting new intent
                Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleMenuItemActivity.class);
                //in.putExtra(KEY_ITEM, name);

                in.putExtra(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
                in.putExtra(KEY_ITEM_NAME,name);
                in.putExtra(KEY_PRICE, cost);

                //in.putExtra(KEY_DESC, description);
                startActivity(in);

            }
        });
    }
}
```

My problem is i am not getting the value of category_name. I tried with nested loop but its all the same. please help me . what should i change in the code.

This  is my xmlParser

```
public class XMLParser {


// constructor
public XMLParser() {

}

/**
 * Getting XML from URL making HTTP request
 * @param url string
 * */
public String getXmlFromUrl(String url) {
    String xml = null;

    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        xml = EntityUtils.toString(httpEntity);

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    // return XML
    return xml;
}

/**
 * Getting XML DOM element
 * @param XML string
 * */
public Document getDomElement(String xml){
    Document doc = null;
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    try {

        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        InputSource is = new InputSource();
            is.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(xml));
            doc = db.parse(is); 

        } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (SAXException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("Error: ", e.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return doc;
}

/** Getting node value
  * @param elem element
  */
 public final String getElementValue( Node elem ) {
     Node child;
     if( elem != null){
         if (elem.hasChildNodes()){
             for( child = elem.getFirstChild(); child != null; child = child.getNextSibling() ){
                 if( child.getNodeType() == Node.TEXT_NODE  ){
                     return child.getNodeValue();
                 }
             }
         }
     }
     return "";
 }

 /**
  * Getting node value
  * @param Element node
  * @param key string
  * */
 public String getValue(Element item, String str) {     
        NodeList n = item.getElementsByTagName(str);        
        return this.getElementValue(n.item(0));
    }
```

Comment: @derekerdmann sorry i cant get what you are changing

Comment: The first line of code in the last block wasn't indented, I just pushed it over to be in the same formatted block. You can view the diff by clicking on "edited N mins ago" at the bottom of the question.

Comment: Also, check out the FAQ for more info on edits: http://stackoverflow.com/faq#editing

Comment: got it or not than if not than i add my ans

Comment: @khan sorry for replying late i will be checking

Comment: @divaNilisha got output or not

Comment: first check in log value u got name first cat and item of first itemcategory and after get for second item category

Comment: i am seeing in logcat as 05-18 11:05:47.351: E/catname(19510): ICECREAM
05-18 11:05:47.351: E/itemname(19510): SOFTY
05-18 11:05:47.351: E/itemname(19510): STICK
05-18 11:05:47.351: E/itemname(19510): CONE
05-18 11:05:47.351: E/catname(19510): PIZZA
05-18 11:05:47.351: E/itemname(19510): PIZZA-HOT
05-18 11:05:47.351: E/itemname(19510): PIZZA-CRISPY

Comment: but not price . and strange thing in my xml i am seeing value only of one item of icecream(cone) and one item of pizza(pizza crispy)

Answer (score 1):

try this way

```
NodeList n,ncategories;
Element e;
static final String KEY_ITEMCATEGORY= "item_category";
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> menuItems = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


   ncategories = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_MENU);

   for(int i=0;i<ncategories.getLength();i++){
       e=(Element)ncategories.item(i);
       n=e.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEMCATEGORY);

       for(int c=0;c<n.getLength();c++){ 
         HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
          e=(Element)n.item(c);

        String category= parser.getValue(e, KEY_CATEGORY).toString();
          Log.e("catname", parser.getValue(e, KEY_CATEGORY).toString());
          map.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);

          NodeList  ns=e.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
          for(int j=0;j<ns.getLength();j++){

             e=(Element)ns.item(j);
             Log.e("itemname", parser.getValue(e,KEY_ITEM_NAME).toString());
             Log.e("itemprice", parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRICE).toString()+"\n");
             map.put(KEY_ITEM_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM_NAME));
             map.put(KEY_PRICE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRICE));

          }
     menuItems.add(map);

   }
```

Comment: the class which i have used for parsing u replace it by ur  xmlParser class

Comment: @divaNilisha if u get output than let me infrom

Comment: i am seeing in logcat as 05-18 11:05:47.351: E/catname(19510): ICECREAM
05-18 11:05:47.351: E/itemname(19510): SOFTY
05-18 11:05:47.351: E/itemname(19510): STICK
05-18 11:05:47.351: E/itemname(19510): CONE
05-18 11:05:47.351: E/catname(19510): PIZZA
05-18 11:05:47.351: E/itemname(19510): PIZZA-HOT
05-18 11:05:47.351: E/itemname(19510): PIZZA-CRISPY

Comment: but not price . and strange thing in my xml i am seeing value only of one item of icecream(cone) and one item of pizza(pizza crispy)

Comment: @divaNilisha not getting u i have check in my code and get price too in logcat

Comment: the strange thing is is i am not seeing the logcat value same as my xml parsed in mobile screen

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11407/discussion-between-khan-and-divanilisha)

Answer (score 0):

You are retrieving list of item elements and trying to find category_name in item element. However, looking at your xml, category_name is sibling of item element, not child. So you will not get category name in that way. 
You might want to retrieve list of item_category and then populate items from it.

```
NodeList nl_categories = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM_CATEGORY);

for(int i = 0; i < nl_categories; i++)
{
    Element e = (Element) nl.item(i);
    String category = parser.getValue(e,KEY_CATEGORY);

    NodeList nl = e.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);

    // looping through all item nodes <item>
    for (int j = 0; j < nl.getLength(); j++) 
    {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(j);

        map.put(KEY_CATEGORY, category);
        map.put(KEY_ITEM_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_PRICE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRICE));

        menuItems.add(map);
    }
}
```

Comment: i do not want to change in xml could you please tell me the code?

Comment: You don't need to change the xml for that. Just change the way you are retrieving items a bit. Retrieve nodelist of item_category first, retrieve category_name and then retrieve items under that category.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
    NodeList nl_Cat = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM_CATEGORY);
    for (int i = 0; i < nl_Cat.getLength(); i++) 
    {
      HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
      Element cat = (Element) nl_Cat(i);
      NodeList nl = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
      for (int j = 0; j < nl.getLength(); j++) 
      {
        Element e = (Element) nl.item(j);
        map.put(KEY_ITEM_NAME, parser.getValue(e, KEY_ITEM_NAME));
        map.put(KEY_PRICE, parser.getValue(e, KEY_PRICE));
       }
      menuItems.add(map);
     }
```

Hope this works!